# Error whilst installing magento extension- package file is invalid

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We are trying to install a custom extension into Magento that I have packed up.
I can install it locally without issue but my client is getting the below error in Magento connect:

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
"./app/code/local/" already exists
```

This extension is for the community channel.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your packaged version thinks it needs to create the `local` folder, except this (standard-ish) folder already exists in your client system.  I'd check your packaging settings and make sure there's no instruction that `app/code/local` be added as a stand alone item.

Comment: Thanks. I've instructed the client to check if they have anything in there, and if they don't, delete the folder, although my package doesn't reference the local code pool anywhere so i'm a bit puzzled at the moment!

Comment: I just checked and I had a blank row when creating the package! Thankyou Alan Storm!

Comment: @Lock Happy to help — the connect packager is the worst.